# Does the quantized estimate give the same MSE limit as the non-quantized estimate?

Tags: limits, analysis, statistics, signal-processing

**Setup:** Given that we have a signal $\beta\in\{0,1\}^p$ that we want to estimate. We have an estimate $\hat{\beta}\in\mathbb{R}^p$ (entries could be continuous) such that the mean squared error
$$
\frac{1}{p}\|\hat{\beta}-\beta\|_2^2
\rightarrow
0
\text{ as $p\rightarrow\infty$.}
$$

**Question:** Given that I quantize the entries of $\hat{\beta}$ such that
$$
\tilde{\beta}_j
=
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{ if $\hat{\beta}_j>0.5$} \\
0 &\text{ if $\hat{\beta}_j\leq0.5$}.
\end{cases}
$$
I believe (intuitively) that we have
$$
\frac{1}{p}\|\tilde{\beta}-\beta\|_2^2
\rightarrow
0
\text{ as $p\rightarrow\infty$.}
$$
Is there a formal way to show this? In other words, does quantization of the estimate affect its limiting MSE?